# Creating multiple VMs & assigning role to those VMs in Azure using Terraform. (Stuck with for_each loop)

Tags: azure, csv, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rbac

I am trying to create multiple Virtual machines in azure. I am passing the vm name values using a CSV file as shown below.

[image]

Further I plan to use the email column to assign these user reader role on the vm, basically I plan to create 1 vm for each name in my csv and assign that guy reader role over corresponding vm.

I was able to create Vms based on my CSV file successfully but when it comes to assign roles I am having trouble in understanding how to do it.

Below is my code for VM creation:

```
    terraform {
    required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "2.77.0"
      }
    azuread = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azuread"
      version = "~> 2.0.0"
      }}}

provider "azuread" {
  tenant_id = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
}

data "azurerm_client_config" "example" {
}

locals {
  group_names = csvdecode(file("./test.csv"))
  users     = { for r in local.group_names : r.email => r }
  
}


data "azurerm_subnet" "exisiting_subnet" {
  name                 = "default"
  virtual_network_name = "rg-sarmad-calico-001-vnet"
  resource_group_name  = "rg-sarmad-calico-001"
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "new_terraform_vm_nic" {
  for_each = {for group_names in local.group_names : group_names.names => group_names}
  name = "nic-${each.value.names}-001"
 
  location            = "westeurope"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_subnet.exisiting_subnet.resource_group_name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "internal"
    subnet_id                     = data.azurerm_subnet.exisiting_subnet.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "new_terraform_vm" {
  for_each = {for group_names in local.group_names : group_names.names => group_names}
  name =      "vm-${each.value.names}-001"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_subnet.exisiting_subnet.resource_group_name
  location            = "westeurope"
  size                = "Standard_F2"
  admin_username      = "adminuser"
  admin_password      = "P@$$w0rd1234!"
  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.new_terraform_vm_nic[each.key].id]
  os_disk {
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
    offer     = "WindowsServer"
    sku       = "2016-Datacenter"
    version   = "latest"
  }
}
```

using for_each loop I am able to create VMS, now I want to assign the users in my csv roles on these VMS using their emails & these usere already exist in AD, so i wrote the below code:

```
data "azuread_user" "user" {
    for_each = {for group_names in local.group_names : group_names.email => group_names}
    user_principal_name = each.value.email
}


resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "new_terraform_vm_rbac" {
# for_each = {for group_names in local.group_names : group_names.names => group_names}
  for_each               = data.azuread_user.user

  scope                =  "/subscriptions/${data.azurerm_client_config.example.subscription_id}/resourceGroups/${data.azurerm_subnet.exisiting_subnet.resource_group_name}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/${"vm-${each.value.names}-001"}" 
  role_definition_name = "Reader"
  principal_id         = data.azuread_user.user[each.key].object_id
}
```

I have two for each loops in "azurerm_role_assignment" the first one is commented but using that loop i can grab the names from CSV which is needed below in defining the scope of the role assignment & I also need data from azuread_user and that would be used in defining principle_id in "azurerm_role_assignment".

I am stuck and do not understand how can I achieve this, I am looking for any suggestion possible.

Comment: Do you have an example of how ` data.azuread_user.user` looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `principal_id= data.azuread_user.user[each.value.email].object_id` instead of  `principal_id = data.azuread_user.user[each.key].object_id`.

So your over all code will be as below:

```
    terraform {
    required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "2.77.0"
      }
    azuread = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azuread"
      version = "~> 2.0.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azuread" {
}

provider "azurerm" {
    features{}
}

data "azurerm_client_config" "example" {
}

locals {
  group_names = csvdecode(file("C:/test.csv"))
  users     = { for r in local.group_names : r.email => r }
}

data "azurerm_subnet" "exisiting_subnet" {
  name                 = "default"
  virtual_network_name = "ansuman-vnet"
  resource_group_name  = "resourcegroup"
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "new_terraform_vm_nic" {
  for_each = {for group_names in local.group_names : group_names.names => group_names}
  name = "nic-${each.value.names}-001"
 
  location            = "West US 2"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_subnet.exisiting_subnet.resource_group_name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "internal"
    subnet_id                     = data.azurerm_subnet.exisiting_subnet.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "new_terraform_vm" {
  for_each = {for group_names in local.group_names : group_names.names => group_names}
  name =      "vm-${each.value.names}-001"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_subnet.exisiting_subnet.resource_group_name
  location            = "West US 2"
  size                = "Standard_F2"
  admin_username      = "adminuser"
  admin_password      = "P@$$w0rd1234!"
  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.new_terraform_vm_nic[each.key].id]
  os_disk {
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }
  

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
    offer     = "WindowsServer"
    sku       = "2016-Datacenter"
    version   = "latest"
  }
}

data "azuread_user" "user" {
    for_each = {for group_names in local.group_names : group_names.email => group_names}
    user_principal_name = each.value.email
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "new_terraform_vm_rbac" {
 for_each = {for group_names in local.group_names : group_names.names => group_names}
  scope                =  "/subscriptions/${data.azurerm_client_config.example.subscription_id}/resourceGroups/${data.azurerm_subnet.exisiting_subnet.resource_group_name}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/${"vm-${each.value.names}-001"}" 
  role_definition_name = "Reader"
  principal_id         = data.azuread_user.user[each.value.email].object_id

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.new_terraform_vm
  ]
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Note:**

You have to use `depends_on =[azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.new_terraform_vm]` in the role assignment block as the role assignment will get created first if the depends on is not provided and you will get an error after the resources are created that role assignment was not set because the VM was not found like below. Also for role assignment you need to have owner access to the subscription or at least the resource-group where you are trying to assign the roles.

[image]